# BSON Error in Jetty Custom Configuration for persisting sessions in mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jetty, bson

I've been facing this error for a long time, I was trying to configure jetty in my demo project where I was trying to persist sessions in MongoDB.

**This is the Main Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.mongodb.Bytes cannot access its superclass org.bson.BSON (com.mongodb.Bytes and org.bson.BSON are in unnamed module of loader 'app')at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

**My Config Class**

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.eclipse.jetty.nosql.mongodb.MongoSessionDataStoreFactory; import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server; import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionCache; import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionCache; import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler; import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServerCustomizer; import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory; import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer; import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;@Configuration public class JettyConfig {

@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory
                > webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> {
        if (factory instanceof JettyServletWebServerFactory) {
            ((JettyServletWebServerFactory) factory).addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer());
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer() {
    return (Server server) -> {
        SessionHandler sessionHandler = null;
        try {
            sessionHandler = sqlSessionHandler();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        server.setSessionIdManager(sessionHandler.getSessionIdManager());
        server.setHandler(sessionHandler);
    };
}

public static SessionHandler sqlSessionHandler() {
    SessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();
    try {
        SessionCache sessionCache = new DefaultSessionCache(sessionHandler);
        sessionCache.setSessionDataStore(
                mongoDataStoreFactory("localhost","bson", "sessions").getSessionDataStore(sessionHandler)
        );
        sessionHandler.setSessionCache(sessionCache);
        sessionHandler.setHttpOnly(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sessionHandler;
}

private static MongoSessionDataStoreFactory mongoDataStoreFactory(String host, String dbName, String collectionName) {
    MongoSessionDataStoreFactory mongoSessionDataStoreFactory = new MongoSessionDataStoreFactory();
    mongoSessionDataStoreFactory.setHost(host);
    mongoSessionDataStoreFactory.setDbName(dbName);
    mongoSessionDataStoreFactory.setCollectionName(collectionName);
    return mongoSessionDataStoreFactory;
}
```

}

**My Pom File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for bson</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-nosql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I did alot of research about this but no luck yet in resolving the error. Here i am using old version of spring boot and java as i have to resolve this error in my old project. I'm thinking that there is a conflict between driver from jetty noSql dependency and spring boot starter mongoDb Dependency

Comment: Spring Boot version `2.3.0.RELEASE` (released May 2020) uses Jetty version `9.4.28.v20200408`.  All of Jetty 9.x was [declared End of Community Support back in June 2022](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/7958), you should be using Jetty 12 and a newer version of Spring Boot at this point in time.

Comment: Also, Jetty `9.4.28.v20200408` (the version you are using) uses Mongo version `2.13.2` and does not support newer versions of MongoDB backend.  Your version of Jetty also has many vulnerabilities fixed in later versions of Jetty see https://eclipse.dev/jetty/security_reports.php